# buildozer fails to create apk. java error?

Tags: java, buildozer

My buildozer configuration has suddenly stopped working. Everything has been working fine, but something must have changed - I don't know what. Maybe there's a problem with java - know I have a problem with geany and pyCharm, both of which use java

a section of my buildozer log is
[image]

My java version is

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I cannot answer this because I have not found a solution. I have instead taken the nuclear option and moved to a new installation of Ubuntu. Works perfectly but at the cost of some hours getting everything set up